How to add a nullable json field to a struct and load from yaml
I have a yaml file:
campaign:
  name: Welcome Campaign
  type: new
  start_date: 08/12/2024
  end_date: 10/12/2024
  metadata:
    channel: sms

I am trying to load it into the following struct
#[derive(Insertable, serde::Deserialize, Debug)]
#[diesel(table_name = campaigns)]
pub struct CampaignInsertable {
    #[serde(rename = "name")] // Maps the `name` key in the YAML to `cpg_name`
    pub cpg_name: String,
    #[serde(rename = "type")] // Maps the `type` key in the YAML to `cpg_type`
    pub cpg_type: String,
    #[serde(with = "date_format")]
    pub start_date: chrono::NaiveDateTime,
    #[serde(with = "date_format")]
    pub end_date: chrono::NaiveDateTime,
    // need a holder for metadata
}

this is the relevant code
let yaml: serde_yaml::Value = serde_yaml::from_str(&content)
                            .map_err(|e| format!("Failed to parse YAML in file {:?}: {}", file_path, e))?;

println!("{:?}", yaml["campaign"]["metadata"]);

if let Some(campaign_data) = yaml.get("campaign") {let campaign: CampaignInsertable = serde_yaml::from_value(campaign_data.clone()).map_err(|e| format!("Failed to deserialize 'campaign' in file {:?}: {}", file_path, e))?;
      campaigns.push(campaign);
} else {
       return Err(format!("Missing 'campaign' key in file {:?}", file_path).into());
}

this works as long as I dont have the metadata as an attribute in the struct. I have been unable to add that to the struct and get a correct working code. It always leads to serializatioon or some other errors and the code doesn't run.
How can I add the metadata which is a nested field. This is a field of type json and is nullable as in it may or may not exist.
I tried to add metadata in the following way to my struct:
    #[serde(rename = "metadata")]
    pub meta_data: Option<serde_json::Value>,

but I get serilization errors
error[E0277]: the trait bound `serde_json::Value: diesel::Expression` is not satisfied
  --> src/models/campaigns.rs:22:10
   |
22 | #[derive(Insertable, serde::Deserialize, Debug)]
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `diesel::Expression` is not implemented for `serde_json::Value`, which is required by `serde_json::Value: AsExpression<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Jsonb>>`


Can you edit your question to include the metadata struct that you tried adding?
